# How to make sheet dynamic

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Seeking for input on this. On the following code, what I'm doing is copying data from a sheet MayData.csv and pasting into Master2017.xlsx.

Master2017 is the main spreadsheet and contains data that is updated monthly. 
Hence, the MayData.csv will change depending on the month (JuneData.csv, JulyData.csv, and so on...)

How can I make it such that the xxxData.csv is dynamic? Right now I try running the Macros but have to change the name of the sheet every time.

Here is what the code more or less looks like (I included only portion of it just to be brief):

```
Dim intChoice As Long
Dim strPath As String
Dim intUsedRows As Integer
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Long

'Open Selected File
Workbooks.Open (strPath)
Columns("C:D").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("F:H").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("G:H").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("B:B").Select
Windows("Master 2017.xlsx").Activate
Windows("MayData.csv").Activate
Columns("B:E").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Windows("Master 2017.xlsx").Activate
Windows("MayData.csv").Activate
Columns("I:S").Select
```

Comment: If there's only one "xxxData.csv" workbook open at any time then you could loop through all open workbooks and find the match.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim. That's the one thing I'm not sure how to approach.

Comment: You can use Data tab > From Text, and select the columns to skip in the wizard http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/importtext.asp

Answer (score 0):

Is the user selecting the CSV file? If Yes then when you open it you can set a workbook variable so you can refer to it later.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
'...
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
'...
With wb.Sheets(1)
    .Columns("C:D").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    .Columns("F:H").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    .Columns("G:H").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End With 
'...
```